# Does scheduling batch script to run every 2 seconds cause performance issues?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I learned some basic Batch scripting and wrote the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.jpg (
move *.jpg batch_IMAGES
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.gif (
move *.gif batch_IMAGES
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.png (
move *.png batch_IMAGES
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.mp4 (
move *.mp4 batch_VIDEOS
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.mp3 (
move *.mp3 batch_AUDIO
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.flv (
move *.flv batch_VIDEOS
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.gif (
move *.gif batch_IMAGES
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.pdf (
move *.pdf batch_PDF
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.rar (
move *.rar batch_RAR
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.zip (
move *.zip batch_RAR
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.exe (
move *.exe batch_PROGRAMS
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.msi (
move *.msi batch_PROGRAMS
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.txt (
move *.txt batch_TXT
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.log (
move *.log batch_TXT
)
if EXIST C:\Users\ConquerJS\Desktop\*.lnk (
move *.lnk batch_PROGRAMS
)
```

It checks for any files with the extensions listed and moves them into appropriate folders. I have it running every 2 minutes but I want to run it every 2 or 5 seconds.

Since I know nothing about how batch scripts utilize CPU, I was wondering if this will cause performance issues, and if so, if there's a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Honestly, it depends on your machine. You'll have to play with the values to find the sweet spot. On my machine, that's every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code like:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg *.gif) do (
    move "%%i" batch_PROGRAMS
)
```

I just put two extensions, put the rest to do what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: Very nice thanks!  But do you see any performance issues in running this every two seconds to cleanup my desktop?

Comment: @Rup It depends, I guess, of how many files and the size of them you have in your desktop. Although I believe you can increase a little bit more the time between clenaups, unless your desktop gets messy too quickly.

Comment: The only quick idea is to prepend the `move` command line by [`start "" /B`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html), so the `move` commands executed in the `for` loop iterations run parallelly...